# Implementing email contact form to a static website

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, email

I am currently developing a little static SPA in vue.js for a client and he wants me to integrate a contact form sending a message to his business gmail account. So my question is: what is the easiest way to do that with keeping in mind that I plan to host his website with Amazon https://aws.amazon.com/fr/websites/?nc2=h_ql_sol_use_web ? In the best case I will select S3 or lightsail if need some back end but I would prefer to avoid any server sided work and configurations just for sending a mail.

Comment: Since you don't want a backend so instead of using the aws sdk, directly use the aws api sedning mails using SNS or SES. But I would recommend you should not do this since you're creating a static website so those pages will be downloaded on client's machines. So it would be hard to keep the secrets such as aws credentials etc.

Comment: possibly integrate a third part system that lets you add the widget code, which submits thru their server (no backend stuff required on your part).  I can't personally recommend any in particular, but as an example google throws up formspree.io which offers this type of thing.

Comment: Yes one solution I was thinking about was to use a third party system to do the interface between the website and the google API but i don't think I can afford to explain my client that it will need to bill for anything than hosting and Domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some third-party solutions like these ones are offering "Email APIs":

- https://www.mailgun.com/email-api/
- https://elasticemail.com/email-api

Or solutions like this:

- https://formsubmit.co
- https://formspree.io/

Comment: Thank you, I will to take a look onThe first two, they seem to be what I need and cost nothing .

Answer (score 1):

You can use form backend services, such as:

- [usebasin.com](https://usebasin.com)
- [formcarry.com](https://formcarry.com)
- [formkeep.com](https://formkeep.com)